# Someone please explain to me ths big O complexity between these two java codes? I m so confused?

Tags: big-o

```
      for ( int i = n, i>0; i / = 2) {
          for ( int j = 1, j<n; j * = 2) {
              for ( int k = 0, k<n; k += 2) {
               } // not nested
          }
      }
```

Answer: O(n(log n)^ 2), (2 is to the square root by the way)
The two outer loops are all log n, because it's having, and the inner one is N because it is halving right?

For this code, the correct answer is O(n) ^ 2, I understand the outer loop is n, and the middle loop is log n, and the inner loop should be n too. so why is the answer not N * N * log n?

```
 for( int i = n; i > 0; i - -) {
     for( int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2 ) {
         for( int k = 0; k < j; k++ ) {
             // constant number C of operations
         }
     }
 }
```

Finally, how do I know when to add or multiply loops? if two loops are nested I just multiply them right? and when do I take the greatest N value over the other loops?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is #2 formatted for readability:

```
for( int i = n; i > 0; i --) 
  for( int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2 ) 
    for( int k = 0; k < j; k++ )
      action
```

Forget the i-loop; we know it multiplies the inner bits by N.

The number of times action gets done by the nested j-, k-loops is then

1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... N.  (If N is not a power of 2, replace it with the next lower power of 2.)

Put this in binary and sum it.  For my example, let's let N be 16, but you can easily generalize.

```
00001
00010
00100
01000
10000
```

which sums to

```
11111
```

which is 2*N-1, or O(N).

Multiplying that by the i-loop range of N gives us O(N^2).

Interesting problem!

Answer (score 0):

the outer and middle loops execute the same number of times, each sqrt(n). the inner loop executes n/2 times. Since they're nested, yes you multiply them together, for a total of sqrt(n)*sqrt(n)*n/2 critical step executions. This equals n^2/2, for which the limit as n approaches infinity is n^2, so it's in the O(n^2) classification of functions. You don't really just take the greatest N value, you take the asymptotic limit, when asked which family the function belongs to.